# nginx -s stop and -s quit what is the difference?

Tags: nginx

I can stop nginx server using `nginx -s stop` or `nginx -s quit`.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Quit is a graceful shutdown. Nginx finishes serving the open connections before shutdown

Stop is a quick shutdown where is terminates in between serving the connection

http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine

Comment: I'm reading the link but it seems the difference between `-s stop` and `-s quit` isn't explained. It was necessary to additionally read [the source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/os/unix/ngx_process.c#L39-L83) to confirm this answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

`-s stop` terminates the nginx process immediately while `-s quit` does a graceful shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

`SIGQUIT` causes nginx to break if it listens on Unix domain sockets.  It will fail to clean up sockets, then immediately terminate on next invocation because it can't create sockets at paths which already exist.

`SIGTERM` causes nginx to shut down into a consistent state from which it can start back up.  The daemon removes any Unix domain sockets, leaves all caches in a usable state, and so forth.

You basically never want to use QUIT.

Comment: The Unix domain sockets issue seems to be due to an [open issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/753) in nginx.  However, if you aren't using this type of socket, it seems clear that the `quit` option is [documented](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/runtime-control/) as the way to do a graceful exit.